# Is there a possibility the company can block my b1/b2 visa?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas

I have a pending issue with my company and they are the one who processed my visa.can the company block my visa? Are there any chances that I won't be able to travel back in the US?

Answer (score 4):

In short, **no**.  The visa is issued by the United States, not your company, and thus cannot be cancelled by your company.

*However*, you still need to be able to explain why you're going to the US and demonstrate why you're going to go back home.  If you can't say "visiting your company" anymore, you'll need to come up with another reason.  Fortunately for you, since B1/B2 also allows tourism, you can always go back as a tourist.